# Showing only upper levels in ToC (ClassicThesis template)

Tags: classicthesis

I try to limit levels in ToC so that only Parts and Chapters would be included in it. Setting the counter does not do the trick, e.g.

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
```

The template is ClassicThesis. There seems to be no `\tableofcontents` command, so perhaps I am misplacing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example of what you're trying that fails? For me `\documentclass{report}\usepackage{classicthesis}\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}\begin{document}\tableofcontents\chapter{foo}\section{bar}\end{document` does work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I added "\setencounter..." after" \usepackage":

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

in classicthesis-config.tex. No change, unfortunately. I cannot post a minimal example, because the header and config are so huge. No idea what to leave out...

Comment: Copy over your header along with a minimal document body (like the one in my comment). Comment everything out, then start to comment packages back in which you think are related to your problem until your erroneous behaviour shows up again. Then post what's left. (Bisectioning might be a good idea to speed things up a bit)